# how to tell scope that it will return single object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope

Am trying this out

```
@user.orders.of(:some_type).for_today
```

business rule says a user can place single order of any type per day, being applied this through callbacks etc. I know that `for_today`, I want it to return single object. That means I want to make scope `for_today` return a single object but not an array. However all followings returns array

#### 1

```
scope :of, lambda{ |type| where(:order_type => type) }
scope :for_today, where(" created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? ", Date.today, Date.tomorrow)
```

#### 2

```
scope :of, lambda{ |type| where(:order_type => type) }
scope :for_today, where(" created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? ", Date.today, Date.tomorrow).limit(1)
```

#### 3

```
scope :of, lambda{ |type| where(:order_type => type) }
scope :for_today, where(" created_at BETWEEN ? AND ? ", Date.today, Date.tomorrow).first
```

and then I do not see any other option calling again `first` in my code

```
@user.orders.of(:some_type).for_today.first
```

I guess, it is correct the way it is working, because developer gets to know that she is fetching out 1st record out, which makes more sense, else there is no way to guess whether it returns array or single object. But still, considering my business rules I would expect that `for_today` should return single object, and hence wanted to know, is there any way to tell `scope` that it is going to return single object so do not package it using array.

Comment: I don't think that is supported. You can simply use a class method that calls the scope and adds a `.first`.

Comment: And just FYI, here are [some little known AR nuggets](http://blog.mitchcrowe.com/blog/2012/04/14/10-most-underused-activerecord-relation-methods/)

Comment: I suggest not to even write your own custom "scope extension" to do this, since you would be breaking convention. Everyone expects a scope to return an array, so if you were to change the scope to not return one, that would be bad. And you don't gain anything by doing so; it will only add to confusion and maybe elicit expletives from your colleagues.